# Ubuntu 22.10 Bluetooth Keyboard Driver

Tags: bluetooth

my Logitech YR0073 Keyboard does show up in -> Settings -> Bluetooth (Devices): MX Keys Mac

But when I click it, nothing happens and I can not pair it with my Raspberry 4.

Any advice? Thanks in advance!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qftXz.jpg)

Comment: Assuming everything is turned on in the computer. Have you followed the steps at the keyboard for pairing?

Comment: Well, I have my Apple Ipad next to the computer and it works there w/o problems. So I don‘t know what to do more for the computer. Keyboard is switched and detected.

Comment: Is the keyboard already connected to the Apple device? Sometimes a Bluetooth device can only be connected to one thing at a time.

Comment: Yep - when it is connected, I can use it there. But I disconnect it of course to use it on my Raspberry.

Comment: Discount it from the Apple device for that matter take it to another room and make sure it is powered off. Then try and pair the keyboard with the Ubuntu computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem connecting bluetooth headset. I found Blueman in Ubuntu Software and i installed it. I was only able to connect to my bluetooth device by searching in Blueman. Blueman solved my problem and i hope it yours too.

Have a nice day :)